# Data not posting on mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb

hi guys hope all of you are fine ..... i am working on mongodb . i am trying to connect from mongodb by sending post request from node.js to mongodb . ..... i am successfully connected with mongodb but i am not able to post data in my collection of mongodb.....this is my code of post request

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const User = require('../DB/User');
const route = express.Router();

route.post('/', async (req, res) => {
  const { firstName, lastName } = req.body;
  let user = {};
  user.firstName = firstName;
  user.lastName = lastName;
  let userModel = new User(user);
  await userModel.save();
  res.json(userModel);
});

module.exports = route;
```

can anyone help me how to fix this?

Comment: Do you get any error? Also did you import `express` like this `const express = require("express")` before `const route = express.Router();`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

before you can send requests to MongoDb, you should initialize it:

```
import { connect } from 'mongoose'; // MongoDB ORM
connect(conf.db[conf.env], {
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
})
  .then(() => console.log(`connected to ${conf.db[conf.env]}`))
```

I need to say above code is written in ES6, if you don't use it you need to set Babel or use older code style:

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('url/of/your/db', {
{
  useNewUrlParser: true,
  useUnifiedTopology: true,
  useFindAndModify: false,
  useCreateIndex: true,
}, function (error) {
  if (error) { // do sth with error
  }
  console.log('connenter code hereected successfully');
}
```